# Magento 1 Testing Frameworks

Tags: magento-1.9, testing, unit-tests

Wherever I can, I like to develop software following a [Test Driven Development (TDD)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestDrivenDevelopment) approach. Usually, in PHP that means using [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de).

Ideally, I would like to write both fine and coarse-grained tests. Unittests to help guide the design and quality of my code, integration tests to make sure it all hangs together and high-level outside in acceptance tests to make sure I actually deliver what my customer has asked me to deliver.

Are there any test frameworks out there tailored for Magento which facilitate TDD?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We are using the [EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit) extension which allows you to test almost everything in Magento without modifying any core files.

I recommend the dev branch which is currently more stable than the master.

We also have experience with [Mage-Test](https://github.com/MageTest), but can not recommend it, because it overwrites some core files in the community codePool.

Comment: Yup, I can vouch for that one. We're using it, too.

Comment: EcomDev_PHPUnit I think is the most widely used. +1 on the dev branch. At the last Magento hackathon we put together https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageBehat if you want to run browser based integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tobias, any chance you could roll-up any other test frameworks you know of for Magento into your answer too?

Comment: Totally. It's not very hard to bootstrap Magento into a test framework. I like to keep things simple and light, so I rarely use anything but plain PHPUnit with Magento 1. For me no extra Magento testing framework turned out to be simpler and easier.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something very simple and quick to setup, take a look at [Testify](http://tutorialzine.com/projects/testify/)

I used it in one of my projects to quickly test Model and Helper methods. For an example on how to run it with Magento, check: https://github.com/erfanimani/Ezimport/blob/master/tests/test.php

Comment: That's great, it's like silex for testing!

Answer (score 4):

You could also look at extending the Magento Test Automation Framework which has over 1000 functional tests and which is used to check Magento Community Edition's nightly builds
http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/automate-your-testing-with-the-magento-test-automation-framework/